# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error : String[] not initialized

Tags: java, arrays, string

i want to write a program as it takes input strings from the user(for example bhas1234@gmail.com) and it prints as bhas1234(leaves the characters after @) when i write the below code it shows the following error:

```
import java.util.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Name {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

                Scanner take =new Scanner(System.in);
                int j=0;
                String[] sh;
                String gmail;
                for(j=0;sh[j]!="exit";j++)
                {
                sh[j]= take.nextLine();
                int i=sh[j].indexOf('@');
                gmail= sh[j].substring(0,i);
                System.out.println(gmail);
                }

        }

    }
```

it shows the error as

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>       The local variable sh may not have been initialized

Comment: sh may not have been initialized

Comment: The error pretty much explains what went wrong

Comment: What is the for loop for here anyways?

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize your `String` array.

```
String[] sh = new String[numbefOfIndexes];
```

In Java, there is no way to use an array before having it initialized.

Keep in mind that, even if you initialize it like I did, the values by default are `null` as it is an array of objects, to avoid this, you can fill the array directly like below

```
String[] sh = {"valueOne", "valueTwo"};
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you want to

- do endless loop (while)
- read in a line of input

  - if it equals "exit", quit
  - otherwise either split at "@" and print the first part OR
  - find the "@" char's index and print a substring (what you did). The effects of the two methods are the same. It's only a matter of favor.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error at for loop where you are using sh[j] before it is initialized.

You should change your code to get input from user and check that as string only instead of array of string. I am giving solution as per your code only though. Update your code to:

```
            Scanner take =new Scanner(System.in);
            int j=0;
            String sh;
            String gmail;
            while(!(sh = take.nextLine()).equals("exit"))
            {

               int i=sh.indexOf('@');
               gmail= sh.substring(0,i);
               System.out.println(gmail);
           }
```